# How do I set a different notifications sounds for different contacts?

Tags: contacts, ringtone

If it matters I have an HTC Desire 626s and just want to know if it's possible to set different notification sounds for different contacts and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe this would work for you. 
http://cellphoneforums.net/htc/t380910-htc-desire-626s-transfer-set-custom-ringtones-notification-sounds.html#axzz4DmQpMeQH